# Enneper surface is an injective inmmersed surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

Show that the map $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by, $$\varphi(u,v)=\left(u-\frac{u^3}{3}+uv^2,v-\frac{v^3}{3}+vu^2,u^2-v^2\right),$$ is an injective immersed surface.

The problem is from the book *Curves and Surfaces* by Abate and Tovena.

Comment: the wording is odd. The surface does have self intersections, so the word "injective" does not apply. Locally injective, yes

Comment: You're right! I have a mistake. How can I prove that $\varphi$ is locally injective? Thanks.